# Update SQL with SqlCommand in .NET

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if I have a DTO representing some entity in a SQL Server database and I need to do a an update using `SqlCommand` as text in code

```
UPDATE sometable 
SET someColumn = someValue.... 
WHERE ...
```

and I construct the `update` statement with all the properties of the object will this affect greatly performance versus constructing the update statement to update only the changed properties?

Thank you.

Comment: This question is about your database and has nothing to do with .Net.

Comment: No, there will not be a *great* effect - after all, to update the row, SQL Server will need to load the entire row and write back the entire row anyway - you're not gaining a whole lot when assigning only the changed properties vs. all properties.....

Comment: Since we don't know the internals of MS SQL Server, the best way to make sure is to measure. You may want to see [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b722f6ea-5fe0-4a9b-9cf8-f53b89544ce4/non-clustered-index-effect-of-updating-all-fields-in-a-row-index-field-has-same-value-as-before?forum=sqldatabaseengine) which suggests a convinient way for that. See if it is applicable for you.

Comment: @marc_s but what if some of the columns have indexes? Don't those indexes need to be updated as well? SQL Server may be handling this smartly of course, and do not update the index if the value of that column is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an ORM like NHibernate or Entity Framework then they automatically take care of this for you by only persisting changes when the actual properties on the object are marked as "dirty".

So if an entity (`FooEntity`) class has data members `Bar` and `Baz`, this:

```
FooEntity e = this.repo.GetFoo( 123 );
e.Bar = "a";
e.Baz = "b";
this.db.SaveChanges();
```

Will result in `UPDATE Foo SET Bar = 'a', Baz = 'b' WHERE Id = 123`

However this:

```
FooEntity e = this.repo.GetFoo( 123 );
e.Bar = "a";
this.db.SaveChanges();
```

Will result in `UPDATE Foo SET Bar = 'a' WHERE Id = 123`

(Note that in practice ORMs like these will also check to ensure the other values have remained the same in order to avoid a concurrency conflict where the data in the database changed after your program code loaded it)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my question was for data reader, without using ORMs and I was concerned with the performance.